# Why does the path command doesn't work in Docker file

Tags: linux, path, docker, dockerfile

This is my docker file

```
# This is a comment
FROM chapmanb/bcbio-nextgen-devel
MAINTAINER Sabarish Subramanian
RUN mkdir /root/software && cd /root/software && wget http://bio.math.berkeley.edu     /eXpress /downloads/express-1.5.1/express-1.5.1-linux_x86_64.tgz
RUN cd /root && mkdir src && cd src && tar xzf ../software/express-1.5.1-linux_x86_64.tgz &&  PATH=$PATH:/root/src/express-1.5.1-linux_x86_64 && export PATH && echo $PATH
```

In the new docker container the path is not set.Kindly suggest me a good way to do this.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by setting a path in an intermediate container?   The EXPORT does not persist.

Answer (score 1):

According to

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/684

you should use the

ENV

command to set $PATH to your value

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#ENV

Comment: I tried writing like this env $PATH /root/src/express-1.5.1-linux_x86_64:$PATH. But it throws error like this :env: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Here is an example   ENV PATH "$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$RBENV_ROOT/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"   from https://gist.github.com/deepak/5933685, it seems you need to put the quotes

Comment: I used this command
 env $PATH "/root/src/express-1.5.1-linux_x86_64:$PATH" && echo $PATH and 

I get this error:
env: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: it should be ENV PATH, not ENV $PATH

Comment: If I use that the error is :env: PATH: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile, here or on a website ?

Comment: The docker file is posted in my question

Comment: well, so I should add the ENV PATH ... in it, I will test soon when I will have a system available

Comment: The folloing Dockerfile works flawlessly FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN useradd -d /home/sensu -m -s /bin/bash sensu
ENV PATH /home/sensu:$PATH if I do `docker build --tag=testn .` and then `docker run -it testn env` I see the expected PATH